# Django tracking anonymous users

Tags: python, django

I am building a system which serves content on external properties.  I would like to track users which have not registered with my site with anonymous unique IDs.  Then, if later they register with my site, I can covert them to regular Django users, but still have information related to their preferences and activities when they were anonymous.

Is there a facility to automatically set a user cookie via Django so that if they user is accepting cookies, I have a user session ID to work with?

I'd prefer not to come up with a custom solution if Django has some path to move from Anonymous to Authenticated users.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you look for sessions. They use cookies, store a unique id into a cookie which is linked to a file on your server containing their data.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: You can also stuff other things in the session like IP addr, agent string, etc. so you can even (possibly) track them across multiple visits to your site.

Answer (score 6):

I've looked for a solution to problems like this in the past. Django Lazy Signup (https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup) looks like it should solve your problem and not force you to reinvent the wheel, though, fair warning I haven't personally used the project.